# How can I insert a variable into an SQL Statement in Razor?

Tags: razor

I am just learning how to make basic stuff with a WebMatrix download, with only some RoR experience.

I would like to use a variable I have created from a login form in an SQL statement checking for rows with the above variable, my code being:

```
var email = foo@live.com
```

This variable is being created just fine using if(IsPost), it works fine.

Then:

```
@{
var sqlQ2 = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE email='foo@live.com'";
var data2 = db.Query(sqlQ2);

    foreach(var row in data2)
    {
        <li>@row.email</li>
    }

}
```

Works correctly, but I would like to replace foo@live.com with the variable email.

Comment: Please make sure you are correctly parameterizing your queries to prevent against SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var rows = db.Query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE email=@0", email);
```